# Ingress vs Ingress + NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I have a barebones deployment, service and ingress configuration. I also use helm charts to bundle them together, but this doesn't matter here, I guess.

So this is my service template:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo-service
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: foo-api
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
spec:
  selector:
    app: foo
    component: foo-api
  ports:
    - name: bar
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

And here's ingress one:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: foo-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I use minikube to set everything up (with nginx ingress addon).

When I set everything up, I could see the deployment/service/pods all in green on the minikube dashboard. After looking at the docs I learned, that my service will be under `$(minikube service foo-service --url}`. But doing this results in a message, that the service has no node port. `minikube ip` however returns a general minikube IP (`192.168.49.2` and when I go there - boom, here's my service, everything is working. It's working on `192.168.49.2:80` port obviously.

This is how the services look like:

```sh
$ minikube service list
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|      NAMESPACE       |                NAME                | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default              | kubernetes                         | No node port |
| default              | foo-service                        | No node port |
| ingress-nginx        | ingress-nginx-controller           | http/80      | http://192.168.49.2:30704 |
|                      |                                    | https/443    | http://192.168.49.2:31834 |
| ingress-nginx        | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | No node port |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                           | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper          | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard               | No node port |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
```

So as you can see, no port for the service.

Now I tried adding `type: NodePort` to my service config and applied that. Doing this and relaunching everything gave me the following services configuration:

```sh
$ minikube service list
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|      NAMESPACE       |                NAME                | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default              | kubernetes                         | No node port |
| default              | foo-service                        | bar/3000     | http://192.168.49.2:30207 |
| ingress-nginx        | ingress-nginx-controller           | http/80      | http://192.168.49.2:30704 |
|                      |                                    | https/443    | http://192.168.49.2:31834 |
| ingress-nginx        | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | No node port |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                           | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper          | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard               | No node port |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
```

With that I can go to `192.168.49.2:80`, but I also can go to `192.168.49.2:30207` - same exact result. Also I can type `minikube service foo-service --url` and get the url, or type `minikube service foo-service` and it will take me to the browser showing me the service (swagger in my case).

So I don't really have a problem per se, but I wanted to ask you guys what's the difference here: should I configure my project with:

- only Ingress
- or with both Ingress and `type: NodePort` specified in the service?

Does either of those solutions have an advantage over the other one?

Comment: exposing as a `NodePort` is in general seen like something you would do for dev only, at least at my workplace. We configure everything via `ingress`

Comment: Thanks for your input. What you said kinda makes sense because, well, I can make use of NodePort when I am debugging/configuring stuff, but then when it would be in production, the service users wont' be needing the port done via NodePort